# Stream python logger messages to popup window

Tags: javascript, python, logging

I am making a website using Django and want to be able to stream my python logger messages to a pop up window.  So far, I've been able to successfully create a static popup window using Django's messages framework and javascript like this:

My Django template:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  function popitup(url,messages) {
    var newwindow=window.open(url,'{{title}}','height=300,width=500');
    var tmp = newwindow.document;
    var html = "";

    tmp.write('<html><head><title>Log Messages</title>');

    if (messages)
      tmp.write('<div class="container"><h2>Log Messages</h2></div><div class="container"><ul class="messages">{% for message in messages %}<li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>{% endfor %}</ul></div>');

    else
      tmp.write('<div class="list-group"><p>No messages here!</p></div>');

    tmp.write('</body></html>');
    tmp.close();

    if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
    return false;
  }
</script>
<div class="container">
  <input id="LogMessages" type="button" value="View Log Messages" onclick="popitup('','{{messages}}','')"/>
</div>
```

I want to switch to python's logger and stream my python messages to a similar popup window.  My python logger is set up so that it writes to a log file and the terminal.  I was thinking of using  `tail  -f` somehow but I'm new to javascript and web development and am not sure the best way to go about doing this.

What is the best way to stream my python log messages to a popup window?